# Rails でdatetime型の値を正しく入れられません．

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

#### 前提

自作アプリのdatetime型のカラムにデータが，コントローラの記述で正しく入れられません．（Rails c  では入れられます．以下の試したことに記載）
イマイチなんでかわからないので，皆さんの力を貸してください．

#### 実現したいこと

User作成時点で，created_atのようなdatetime型のデータを入れたいです．

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

[["email", "xxxxx.com"],
["encrypted_password", "[FILTERED]"],
["created_at", "2022-10-16 21:32:18.541640"], ["updated_at", "2022-10-16 21:32:18.541640"], ["name", "xxxx"], ["birthday", "2022-09-25"], ["received_at", nil]]

このreceived_atがUser作成時点でcreated_atらと同様に入っていてほしいです．

#### 該当のソースコード

```
before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def initialize
    @user.received_at = params[received_at: :Time.current]
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.received_at = Time.now
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Please check your email to activate your account."
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

#### 試したこと

実はこのアプリ自体作り直していて，その際は以下のコードで動いていました．（received_atが期待通りの値を取得していた．）

```
  def initialize
    @user.received_at = params[received_at: :Time.now]
  end


  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    #params[:user]実装は終わっていないことに注意!
    #マスアサインメント脆弱性
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Please check your email to activate your account."
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

なので，一旦そのままコードをコピペしたらなぜか動かなくて，？？？ってなっています．

また，コンソールから確認してみたらそっちではできたので，カラムを追加していないとか，そういったことではなさそうです．

```
irb(main):001:0> user = User.create
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
=> #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: nil, birthday: nil, received_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> user.received_at = Time.now
=> 2022-10-16 21:04:36.530002067 +0900
irb(main):003:0> p user
#<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: nil, birthday: nil, received_at: "2022-10-16 21:04:36.530002000 +0900">
=> #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: nil, birthday: nil, received_at: "2022-10-16 21:04:36.530002000 +0900">
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Ruby 3.1.2
Rails 7.0.4
Devise Gem でユーザー登録実装

Comment: `initialize`をRailsのコントローラーで使うことはまずありません、そのメソッドを削除して試してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます，削除します．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`received_at` は `rails generate migration AddReeivedAtToUser received_at:datetime` などで users テーブルにカラムを追加するマイグレーションを作成し、`rails db:migrate` で DB に反映されているでしょうか? app/models/user.rb の User クラスに `attribute :received_at, :datetime` を追加して済ませていないでしょうか?

後者の場合、rails 上で仮想的なカラムが追加されるだけで save しても DB には反映されません。※DB の users テーブルにはカラム自体が存在しない。

「rails console では入れられる」とのことですが、DB に反映できているか確認されているでしょうか? 具体的には `user.save; user.reload` の様に save 後に reload で DB から読み込み直すと `received_at` が nil になっていないでしょうか?

「アプリ自体作り直していて」とのことですが、マイグレーションファイルの内容は引き継げているでしょうか?

以上の点をまず確認されると良いと思います。

と、実は `received_at` が登録されない件とは直接関係ないと思うので、以降は興味本位の内容です。
提示されたコードに含まれる `initialize` メソッドには突っ込み所が多いです。実際存在するのでしょうか?
突っ込み所:

1. 先の回答にある通り、通常 `initialize` を書きません。
2. その上で、`initialize` が実行されるタイミングでは `@user` は nil (存在しない)ので `@user.received_at =`  はエラー `undefined method 'received_at=' for nil:NilClass` が発生するはずです。
3. `initialize` 内での `params[...]` はエラー `undefined method 'filered_parameters' for nil:NilClass` が発生します。※私も詳しくは理解していませんが、Rails 7.0.4 で発生しました。
4. `:Time.current` とされていますが、 `:Time` はクラスではなくシンボルです。なので `undefined method 'current' for :Time:Symbol` というエラーが発生するはずです。
5. `params[recieved_at: Time.current]` は `{ received_at: Time.current }` というキーで `params` から値と取得するものです。通常 params はハッシュをキーとした値を持たないので `nil` になると思います。なので仮に 2~4 の問題がないとしても `@user.received_at =` には `nil` が代入されると思います。

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございます！　attribute :received_at, :datetime, default: -> { Time.now }を追加したところ，うまいこといきました！

Comment: ただ，すいません，どうしてこれを入れたことでうまいこと言ったのかいまいちわかってないのでまた解説していただけると嬉しいです．前提として，頂いた回答に沿って僕の回答しておくとマイグレーションは作成済みで，DBにも反映させています．（schema.rbにちゃんと入っていたので．．．）ただ，今回機能することになった　”attribute :received_at, :datetime, default: -> { Time.now }”　がどうして必要だったのかいまいちわかっていません．DBにきちんとデータの型も合わせて書いていたのに，どうしてまたModels/User.rbにも書く必要があったのでしょうか？

Comment: いや、むしろ `attribute :received_at` を追加すると DB に反映されなくなるように思いますが、問題なかったしょうか。

Comment: マイグレーションファイルに received_at が含まれているなら、そちらで default を指定した方が良いと思います。
ただし、マイグレーションの default で登録日時を指定する方法(表現・式)は DB 毎に異なるので確認してみてください。
マイグレーションではなく、あくまで Rails 上で対処するなら before_create コールバックを利用することが考えられます。
Railsガイドの[利用可能なコールバック](https://railsguides.jp/active_record_callbacks.html#%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E3%81%AA%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF)あたりを参考にしてください。

Comment: >>いや、むしろ attribute :received_at を追加すると DB に反映されなくなるように思いますが、問題なかったしょうか。  ＞＞＞＞一応確認してみますが，どうして反映されなくなるとお考えなのでしょうか？

Comment: >>マイグレーションファイルに received_at が含まれているなら、そちらで default を指定した方が良いと思います。 ただし、マイグレーションの default で登録日時を指定する方法(表現・式)は DB 毎に異なるので確認してみてください。 マイグレーションではなく、あくまで Rails 上で対処するなら before_create コールバックを利用することが考えられます。 Railsガイドの利用可能なコールバックあたりを参考にしてください。　　＞＞＞資料ありがとうございます，読んでみます．マイグレーションでデフォルトの設定をするのは当初考えました．教えていただいたmodelに書き込むattributeのコードとは振る舞いというか働き方が違うということでしょうか？ちなみに，このreceived_atの使い方としては，一旦ユーザー作成の段階で初期値（現在時刻）をいれたのち，とあるタイミングで適宜その時間を更新するという想定です．